# The Xcode reminder me this:"Reference to generic type 'Set' requires arguments in <...>",How can I solve it?

Tags: swift

```
private let productIdentifier:Set
```

[The error appeared when I add the following private property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIOjA.png)

Comment: Please put more effort in your question.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, the crucial information is **...generic...requires arguments in <...>**.

Answer (score 1):

`Set` is a generic type. You must tell Swift what kind of elements you're going to put in that set. You probably want something like this:

```
private let productIdentifier: Set<String>
```